# How to wrap it inside setTimeout ? if we assume it will take time to receive data from server(here simply txt file) so execute it after some time

Tags: javascript

How to wrap it inside setTimeout ?
Suppose instead of taking data from file if we take data from server and it will take some time to give response ?

```
console.log('Now you are online.');
function callingfun() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'kk1.txt', true);
**strong text**
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        resolve();
      }
      else {
        console.log('some error occured');
        reject();
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
  })
}

callingfun().then(function () { console.log('promise resolved'); }).catch(function () { console.log('promise rejected') });
```

Comment: What makes you think you want to wrap it in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Note: Typically, you'd do `resolve(this.responseText)` or similar. Just `resolve()` on its own doesn't provide any fulfillment value.

Comment: Note 2: Look at using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) instead, but beware of [the footgun in the API](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) that I point out on my anemic little blog.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose instead of taking data from file if we take data from server and it will take some time to give response ?

It doesn't matter, your `onload` handler will be called when the data arrives. You don't need or want `setTimeout` here.

But your code has a couple of issues:

1. It doesn't provide the data to `resolve`, so the promise fulfillment handlers won't see it.
2. You're only checking `status`, not `readyState`. you need to check both.
3. It fails instantly because it's checking `status` without having check `readyState`.

Here are the minimum changes I'd make, see the `***` comments:

```
function callingfun() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {    // ***
        if (this.status === 200) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
          resolve(this.responseText); // ***
        } else {
          console.log('some error occured');
          reject();
        }
      }
    };
    // ** Also handle error
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      reject(e);
    };
    // *** Hook up handlers before either `open` or `send`
    xhr.open('GET', 'kk1.txt', true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
callingfun()
.then(function(data) {
  // *** Use `data` here
  console.log('promise resolved');
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // *** Perhaps use `error` here
  console.log('promise rejected');
});
```

---

But as I said in a comment, look at using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) instead, but beware of the footgun in the API that [I point out on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). Using `fetch`, that would be:

```
fetch('kk1.txt', true)
.then(function(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
  }
  return response.text();
})
.then(function(data) {
  // *** Use `data` here
  console.log('promise resolved');
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // *** Perhaps use `error` here
  console.log('promise rejected');
});
```

Comment: As you mentioned  (-You're only checking status, not readyState. you need to check both-) .Is it necessary to check readyState even if I am not interested to track the progress ?

Comment: @AbhishekPratapsingh - Yes. You have to wait for `readyState` to reach `4` (done). Only at that point does it make sense to look at `status`.